# Move multiple divs on the same page

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mousemove

My problem is when I add a mousemove listener on document, all divs are moving but when I add a mousemove listener on my element, I have to move the cursor slowly.

Here is my code :

```
let componentsItems = document.getElementsByClassName("componentItem");
[].forEach.call(componentsItems, function (componentItem) {
    componentItem.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        let selectedComponent = getComponentToDisplay(event.target.getAttribute("data-exchange"));

        let mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
        let mainElement = document.createElement("div");
        mainElement.innerHTML = "test";

        mainElement.style.position = "absolute";
        mapContainer.appendChild(mainElement);

        mainElement.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            isDown = false;
        });

        mainElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            isDown = true;
            offset = [
                mainElement.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
                mainElement.offsetTop - e.clientY
            ];
        });

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            mousePosition = {
                x: e.clientX,
                y: e.clientY
            };

            let left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]);
            let top = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]);
            if(isDown){
                if(mapContainer.offsetTop < top && mapContainer.offsetWidth > left){
                    mainElement.style.left =  left + 'px';
                    mainElement.style.top = top + 'px';
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

For each component in my menu, I add an onclick listener to appendChild element in the "MapContainer" div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag and drop problem.

The problem is you are attaching multiple mousemove listeners to document, and each one with every one of the different mainElements.

The solution:

Remember which **element** we are about to move.

```
mainElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  isDown = true;
  element = mainElement;
  offset = [
    mainElement.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
    mainElement.offsetTop - e.clientY
  ];
});
```

On the outter scope (outside foreach) create a unique mousemove event listener, and update the **element** that we mousedowned before.

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  mousePosition = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  };

  let left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]);
  let top = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]);
  if(isDown){
    if(mapContainer.offsetTop < top && mapContainer.offsetWidth > left){
      element.style.left =  left + 'px';
      element.style.top = top + 'px';
    }
  }
});
```

Other ways to solve this problem is to create (and delete) the eventlistener on the mousedown and mouseup event handlers respectively. But I believe it's less efficient and definitely more complicated.